# How to change the culture of a number in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, culture, currentculture

I'm sending parameters to paypal as hidden form vars.

but my site's culture is Danish.
So "50,00" is the value for "amount_1"

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="50,00" />
```

I'm using this code that converts the 50 to "50,00"

```
item.PricePaid.ToString("#.00")
```

I believe the number should be like: "1234.56"
Is there a way to set the culture to en-US just on this process? (not side wide)
Or a better way to do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the overload of [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tostring.aspx) that takes an `IFormatProvider` and then use [`GetCultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultureinfo.aspx) to pass in the required culture info:

```
item.PricePaid.ToString("#.00", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Alternatively, you could (probably) specify the invariant culture rather than "en-US":

```
item.PricePaid.ToString("#.00", CultureInfo.InvarianCulture);
```